# I have allowed anonymous access in my SharePoint web app, but still it prompts me for credentials

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

So far what i have done is, i have allowed anonymous user access to my web app from the Central admin. Then I gave permissions to anonymous user from my top level site. Now, when i open y site, the read only page shows, but when i click on my shared documents library, it keeps on asking me for credentials. Also, when i try to access any other lists, sometimes it automatically takes administrator credentials and logs in using admin.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the site is running in LockDown mode. This mode is controlled by `ViewFormPagesLockdown` feature. You can disable this mode by deactivating this feature.

```
$lockdown = get-spfeature viewformpageslockdown

disable-spfeature $lockdown -url http://sitecollectionURL
```

If SP2010 after deactivating , disable and re-enable the anonymous access in the site collection